# Running into undefined method `total_pages' with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

My goal is to have a tag cloud within my posts page which will allow the user to filter posts by clicking on a tag. However, I am running into an undefined method 'total_pages" error after making the following changes to my Post_Controller method:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @posts = Post.visible_to(current_user).where("posts.created_at > ?", 7.days.ago).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to use the acts-as-taggable-on gem, and this logic will show me the posts with the appropriate tags.

The issue happens in the posts/index.html.erb view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h1> Trending </h1>
    <p class="lead"> Active posts this week </p>
    <div id="tag_cloud">
    Tag Cloud:
     <% tag_cloud Post.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
     <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
     <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= render partial: 'posts/post', collection: @posts %>
      <%= will_paginate @posts %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

The will_paginate line will not render all the posts on that page. The work around is getting rid of  `<%= will_paginate @posts %>` and replacing

```
@posts = Post.visible_to(current_user).where("posts.created_at > ?", 7.days.ago).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

with `@posts = Post.all`. However, this gives me an entire page of posts, which is ugly. Does anyone know why I am running into an undefined method 'total_pages' error?

[image]

Comment: there are several identical to this questions on SO, take a moment to go through them - sure you'll find an answer

Comment: Is the error happening when params[:tag] is set or not?

Comment: @FrederickCheung The page loads fine with the posts and cloud tag. However, the error only happens, when I click on a tag to filter the posts. The error is happening when params[:tag] is false.

Comment: @andreydeineko Yeah I looked through those questions, and I've tried require 'will_paginate/array' which I thought might resolve this, but I am still running into the issue.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I added a screen shot of the application, the error happens when I click on a tag (show,test,now,new)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when you're sending a tag (params[:tag]) it is fetching posts with

```
@posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
```

which is lacking the will paginate call. I believe you could get it working by adding the will paginate scope, like this:

```
@posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag]).paginate(...)
```

Comment: Oh goodness..yeah that was the issue..I thought it was the second line of my if else clause that was causing the error...